# Default value in angular js select from Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select

Here is the Scenario

I am getting Data from server in this form

```
$scope.data=[
{"name":"xyz","status":"pending"},
{"name":"abc","status":"completed"},
{"name":"pqr","status":"completed"}
]
```

This Data is Seprate GET call for different status

```
$scope.statusValues=[
{"statusName":"pending","id":"1"},
{"statusName":"completed","id":"2"},
{"statusName":"cancelled","id":"3"},
{"statusName":"custom","id":"4"}
]
```

In HTML:-

```
<div ng-repeat="t in data">{{t.name}}</div>
```

How to Display t.status value inside Select method with more $scope.statusValues

[image]

Comment: Use `ng-selected`  match with `ng-model` like this................................                                 `<select ng-model="status.statusname">
   <option ng-repeat="t in data" title="{{t.title}}" ng-selected="{{t.statusname== status.statusname}}" value="{{t.statusname}}">{{t.statusname}}</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-options` to display all the status and `ng-model` to bind to your data status

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "statusId": "1",
    "status": "completed"
  }, {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "statusId": "2",
    "status": "pending"
  }, {
    "name": "PQR",
    "statusId": "3",
    "status": "assigned"
  }];

  $scope.statusValues = [{
    "statusId": "1",
    "status": "completed"
  }, {
    "statusId": "2",
    "status": "pending"
  }, {
    "statusId": "3",
    "status": "assigned"
  }, {
    "statusId": "4",
    "status": "cancelled"
  }, {
    "statusId": "5",
    "status": "customstatus"
  }, {
    "statusId": "6",
    "status": "customstatus2"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="t in data">
    {{t.name}}
    <select ng-model="t.status" ng-options="s.status as s.status for s in statusValues"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Update arrays as discussed in comments

Comment: Thank You fro Replying !! But still by default status value is not getting selected..as it is coming from server..

Comment: What is the default value ?

Comment: If you run the code snippet you can see that each dropdown has the value of the `status` inside the array `data`.. Thus the default value IS selected

Comment: Yes it will work ..as it is local data..in my case m getting data from server..??can u explain how should i approach.

Comment: Use nested `then` function

Comment: Sorry didnt get your point ?can you give me a code snippet ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129782/discussion-between-weedoze-and-sunny-coder).

Comment: Nice ! Dont forget to mark it as the answer or add your own answer if mine was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use key value pair for combine them.

```
I have created plunker it may helpful.
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sKJhKKimWZiWXR6gUdy4?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You fro Replying !! But still by default status value is not getting selected..as it is coming from server..

Comment: I have created static replace it with server response.

Comment: Exactly.Static data working fine..as soon as I do it with server GET call..it is not selecting default value {{t.status}}